# Actual implementation of JSR-353 (JSON)?

Tags: library, java, json, parser

For handling [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), the following [specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_(technical_standard)) have been published by the [JCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process):

- [*JSR 374: Java™ API for JSON Processing 1.1*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374)
- [*JSR 353: Java™ API for JSON Processing*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353) (1.0 – predecessor to JSR 374)

Built on top of those is the specification for JSON-to-Java [data-binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binding):

- [*JSR 367: Java™ API for JSON Binding (JSON-B)*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367)

Are there any [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation#Computer_science) of these [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)s?

Comment: Inspired by [*What are the API that does implement JSR-353 (JSON) \[closed\]* - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984619/what-are-the-api-that-does-implement-jsr-353-json).

Answer (score 2):

## Reference implementation

[JSON-P](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/) is the reference implementation for JSR 374 (& 353). May or may not be a competitive one, in terms of feature and performance. This code is included as a part of [*Glassfish*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish), the reference implementation of [Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition).

For the binding spec, JSR 367, the reference implementation is [*Eclipse Yasson*](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.yasson).

Answer (score 1):

## Genson

Besides the reference implementation shown in [correct Answer by Yu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/47698/1255), another implementation of JSR 353 is *Genson*. See the [project page](http://owlike.github.io/genson/) and the [GitHub page](https://github.com/owlike/genson).

While I have not used it, the documentation claims to be a complete implementation of JSR 353. I do not know if it has been updated to the follow-up spec, JSR 374.